# Expanding JCombo box pop from a inner JButton

Tags: java, swing

I am facing a issue in expanding combo box popup programmatically from a inner command button.

My target is to expand all the ComboBoxes visible on the UI one after the other and collect a screenshot for each one of them.

Here is the sample code which I tried :

```
void drillDown(Component component) throws InterruptedException{
    if(component instanceof JComboBox){
        JComboBox combo = (JComboBox) component;
        combo.requestFocusInWindow();
        combo.getUI().setPopupVisible(combo, true);

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    else if(component instanceof Container){
        if(((Container) component).getComponents().length>0){
            for(Component component2 : ((Container) component).getComponents() ){
                drillDown(component2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And full code can be found here: 
http://pastebin.com/pU52vZ9b

I am able to successfully expand all the comboboxes when I call the drillDown() method just after 'frame.setVisible(true);'.

But when I try to launch the same from a embedded jButton (please find the screenshot attached). Only the last combobox is getting expanded, Although 
it is iterating though all the Comboboxes and combo.requestFocusInWindow() is returning true everytime.

I also tried calling drillDown() using SwingUtilities.invokeLater() but no luck.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tukBl.png

Comment: You might want to look at `Robot`

Comment: Robot is not a choice for me as the UI is dynamic and the fields are varying based on configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I try to launch the same from a embedded jButton

Code invoked from the ActionListener is executed on the Event Dispatch Thread. This Thread is responsible for painting the GUI and keeping the GUI responsive.

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

This causes the EDT to sleep which means the GUI can't repaint itself until all the code is finished executing so you only see the last combo box displayed.

Don't use Thread.sleep();

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. One solution is to use a `SwingWorker` as described in the tutorial.

Another approach may be to use a Swing Timer. The Timer will schedule events. So every time the Timer fires you display the drop down of a different combo box.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I will try and post the results back.

Comment: SwingWorker is worked for me !!. [Here](http://pastebin.com/KnfPMLxU) is what I have tried.

I'm iterating through the JPanel tree in doInBackground() and doing requestFocusInWindow, setPopupVisible in process() method.

I also tried using [SwingTimer](http://pastebin.com/YWyD34mp) but it is still same issue.